# How to download deprecated Blackberry SDKs?

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to download the correct version of the Blackberry SDK to work on an app a friend started a while back.

When I downloaded the new Eclipse package bundled with the 6.0 SDK, it gives an error compiling the application which seems to be related to the SDK.

I came across the Eclipse package website http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java however it does not seem to work; it begins to download, asks for my credentials, and then fails when I provide my Blackberry Developer Zone login info.

Is there another way to download older versions of the SDK? I couldn't find anything searching Google, and there seems to be some sketchy search results.

Comment: Have you tried contacting support at RIM?  If their standard method for retrieving the SDK is broken, I'm sure they would like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the URL you posted is the update site for the old (v1.1) plugin for Eclipse 3.5.

If you want to use the newer (v1.3) plugin for Eclipse 3.6, the update site is:
http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java

Details on the current Eclipse plugin are available here:
http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp

And for the legacy JDE (probably not what you want), go here:
http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javadevenv.jsp

I'm personally still using the older (v1.1) plugin due to bugs in the new plugin that affect my own project, but I'm not sure where the public download site for the old plugin is these days.